# Add symbol to the end of each string in the file

Tags: bash, text, awk

I have txt file with plain text. There are only text strings, something like:

```
asdasd asd asd asd
asdasdasdasd asd a
asdasdasdasdasdasd
```

I need to add **;** symbol to the end of every string. I need to get:

```
asdasd asd asd asd;
asdasdasdasd asd a;
asdasdasdasdasdasd;
```

How can i make this with awk or another text processing utils?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed 's/$/;/' file
```

sed replace the end of the string with semi-colon.

if awk is needed (as per OP's requirement) :

```
awk '1' ORS=";\n" file
```

Answer (score 2):

*sed* is your friend.

```
sed -i "s/$/;/" filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Open the file in `vi` and issue this command

```
:%s/$/;/g
```